# Can cassandra guarantee the replication factor when a node is resyncing it's data?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Let's say I have a 3 node cluster.

I am writing to node #1.

If node #2 in that cluster goes down, and then comes back up and is resyncing the data from the other nodes, and I continue writing to node #1, will the data be synchronously replicated to node #2?  That is, is the replication factor of that write honored synchronously or is it behind the queue post resync?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes granted that you are reading and writing at a consistency level that can handle 1 node becoming unavailable.

Consider the following scenario:

1. You have a 3 node cluster with a keyspace 'ks' with a replication factor of 3.
2. You are writing at a [Consistency Level](http://docs.datastax.com/en//cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html) of 'QUORUM'
3. You are reading at a Consistency level of 'QUORUM'.
4. Node 2 goes down for 10 minutes.
5. Reads and Writes can successfully continue while node is down since 'QUORUM' only requires 2 (3/2+1=2) nodes to be available.  While Node 2 is down, both Node 1 and 3 maintain ['hints'](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_hh_c.html) for Node 2.
6. Node 2 comes online.  Node 1 and 3 send hints they recorded while Node 2 was down to Node 2.

If a read happens and the coordinating cassandra node detects that nodes are missing data/not consistent, it may execute a ['read repair'](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/architectureClientRequestsRead_c.html)

If Node 2 was down for a long time, Node 1 and Node 3 may not retain all hints destined for it.  In this case, an operator should consider running [repairs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_repair_nodes_c.html) on a scheduled basis.

Also note that when doing reads, if Cassandra finds that there is a data mismatch during a digest request, it will always consider the data with the newest timestamp as the right one (see ['Why cassandra doesn't need vector clocks'](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/why-cassandra-doesnt-need-vector-clocks)).

Comment: At what point is node #2 ready to receive new writes? Is it after it has caught with the writes that happened while it was down? Or can new writes be processed as soon as the node is online but not yet caught up.  

If node #3 goes down before node #2 has fully caught up, what happens to a new write request?

All this, assuming a consistency level that allows for a single node failure in a 3 node cluster.

Comment: @Andy In the example scenario, if one node goes down the write will fail because QUORUM cannot be achieved. In this scenario, 2 nodes should ack the write, for it to succeed. Only a Consistency of ONE will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Node2 will immediately start taking the new writes and also any hints stored for this node by others. It is good idea to run a read repair on the node after it is back up, which will ensure the data is accurate with other nodes.

Note that each column has a timestamp stored against it which will help cassandra determine which data is recent when running node repair.